# Read version from POM in Javascript

Tags: javascript, maven, resources

I have an agular app that is mavenised and I use maven to build and test it
I want to read the version number of the app from the pom and read it in the javascript file

I read that I can achieve this using the resources plugin , so I set it up as

```
<resources>
     <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
</resources>
```

In app.js

```
.constant('config', {
    appName: 
    appVersion: ${project.version},
    apiUrl: 
});
```

This fails. What is teh correct way to read the pom in javascript?

Here is the directory structure 
[image]

Comment: Where is `app.js` located in your project?

Comment: its located here main/src/js

Comment: `main/src/js` is not a standard directory in a Maven project. Can you post your whole directory structure?

Comment: I just posted the directory structure

Comment: Ah `main` is the name of the project. Well, how do you expect Maven do filter a file that is under `src/js` when you specified `<directory>src/main/resources</directory>`? Second question, how is this file used? How does it end up in the final product?